# Problems with gnuplot to plot some images with 3d plot

Tags: gnuplot

So i made a little code to print some points over a spherical surface and i made him too locate all the positions of the center of mass of all the point printed (every time that he print a point he recalculate the position of the center of mass). The positions of the center of mass was printed to one file with i (that was the number of points printed until this moment) and the coordinates x, y and z. And based on script made by a professor of mine i made this script below to run with gnuplot to make a row of images with a ball that moves around the positions of the center of mass and at the final i that could made a video with the images.

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1080,1080

set view equal xyz
fx(t)= system(sprintf("sed -n '%d p' ../dat/cm.dat | cut -f2 -d' '", t))
fy(t)= system(sprintf("sed -n '%d p' ../dat/cm.dat | cut -f3 -d' '", t))
fz(t)= system(sprintf("sed -n '%d p' ../dat/cm.dat | cut -f4 -d' '", t))
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics

t= 1
while(t <= 100000){
    set output sprintf("%d.png", t/10)
    set object circle at fx(t), fy(t), fz(t) size 0.35 fc rgb "#000000" fillstyle solid 1.0
    splot "../dat/cm.dat" u 2:3:4 w l lc rgb "#FFFFFF" t""
    unset object
    t= t+10
}
unset terminal
unset output
```

The problem who bring me here, i tried everything that passed out of my mind, but every time that i run the script the ball that should move around the positions of center of mass is printed so giant that is almost impossible to see the movement, you can see the problem with the size [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wbqd.png). So if someone know what is the problem, i will be grateful.
[image]

p.s.: Maybe this isn't important at all, but sorry for my write i'm not much acquainted with english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first have to set your output and then plot.

```
...
set output sprintf("%d.png", t/10)
splot "../dat/cm.dat" u 2:3:4 w l lc rgb "#FFFFFF" t""
...
```

**Addition:**

I guess I still don't understand your problem.
My understanding so far: you have a huge datafile with for columns: `i,x,y,z`. And `x,y,z` describe a movement in 3D. In the end you want to animate this movement with a sphere or circle, correct? And your problem is that this sphere is too large? Then make the size smaller, e.g. instead of `size 0.35` try `size 0.05`.

Maybe with the following (different) example we will come (iteratively) closer what you want.
By the way:

1. I don't see any need for `sed`, can be done with gnuplot
2. you can create animated GIF with gnuplot

This is just a guess, I could be on the wrong track. Just let me know.

**Code:**

```
### animated movement in 3D
reset session

set term gif animate delay 10 optimize
set output "myAnimation.gif"

# create some test data
set print $Data 
    x0 = y0 = z0 = 0
    do for [i=1:200] {
        x0=x0+rand(0)-0.5; y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5; z0=z0+rand(0)-0.5
        print sprintf("%d %.3f %.3f %.3f",i,x0,y0,z0)
    }
set print

do for  [i=0:199] {
    splot $Data u 2:3:4 w l lc rgb "blue" notitle, \
          '' u 2:3:4 every ::i::i w p pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb "red" notitle
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: yeah that resolve the problem with that strange message in the terminal, i little thing that passed over me. But the ball continue over sized. Thank you for this detail and if someone knows about the size, the question continues open.

Comment: yes, i have 10k positions which i want to plot and make a ball move through that positions. And my problem is with the size, i tried to change the size. But when i change the size the only thing is change is the proportion of the graph e.g if i reduce the size, all the graph have the size reduced and the ball continues giant in proportion. And i doesn't know much about gnuplot, everything i tried here is based on some file that a professor of mine shared with me. And about your code, when you plot the ball what "every ::i::i" do?

Comment: `every ::i::i` basically plots the `i`th row (numbering starts from 0). For details please check the manual or in the gnuplot console type `help every`.